# using properties class and stored procedure to insert into sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, properties

I am using VB.Net 2010. Wrting an insert into a table using stored procedure. Below the code to pass each line of gridview into the class, and then the call to the insert into.

```
For Each dtlRow As GridViewRow In DetailGrid.Rows
    'insert transaction into transaction table.'
    Dim td As New TransactionDetail
    td.CheckNumber = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.CompanyNumber = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.EffectiveDate = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.IndividualId = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.InvoiceNumber = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.NetAmount = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.TransactionType = dtlRow.Cells(1).Text
    td.GroupId = dtlRow.Cells(0).Text
    td.InsertIntoTransactionTable()
Next
```

Below an example of the insert into method with an example of one get,set property.

```
     Private _IndividualId As String
Public Property IndividualId() As String
    Get
        Return _IndividualId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _IndividualId = value
    End Set
End Property


Public Function InsertIntoTransactionTable()
    Dim Connection As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim Command As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim IDKey As Integer = 0
    Connection = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
    Command = New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    Command.Connection = Connection
    Connection.ConnectionString = My.Settings.SqlConn
    Connection.Open()
    Command.CommandText = "tmx.InsertNewTransactionDetail"
    Command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    Command.Parameters.Clear()
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int, 0, "Id")
    Command.Parameters("@Id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
    Command.Parameters.Add("@EffectiveDate", System.Data.SqlDbType.Date)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@TransactionType", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@InvoiceNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@CompanyNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@NetAmount", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@Discount", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@GroupId", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@CheckNumber", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters.Add("@IndividualID", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    Command.Parameters("@EffectiveDate").Value = _EffectiveDate
    Command.Parameters("@TransactionType").Value = _TransactionType
    Command.Parameters("@InvoiceNumber").Value = _InvoiceNumber
    Command.Parameters("@CompanyNumber").Value = _CompanyNumber
    Command.Parameters("@NetAmount").Value = _NetAmount
    Command.Parameters("@Discount").Value = _Discount
    Command.Parameters("@GroupId").Value = _GroupId
    Command.Parameters("@CheckNumber").Value = _CheckNumber
    Command.Parameters("@IndividualID").Value = _IndividualId
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    IDKey = System.Convert.ToInt32(Command.Parameters("@Id").Value)
    Connection.Close()
    Return IDKey
```

My specific question is if this is necessary, and if I am gaining much from performing the call this way. It is much easier than passing as an argument in the method. Would there be danger of another call inserting data into this method before the insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From within the 'For Each .... Next' you are creating a new instance of the TransactionDetail object and then use this instance to set the variouse parameter values and to finally call its InsertIntoTransaction method. Each instance of TransactionDetail will contain its own set of class field variables (created on the heap) for storing the variouse values. The InsterIntoTransaction method only uses its own copy of local variables and makes use of the instance field variables for the values set by the calls to the properties. The method also creates its own private copy of a database connection and its own command instance to run the stored procedure. Therefore everything is issolated. If there was another thread running that also made use of the TransactionDetail class, it to would be completley issolated from any other instance. Finally, each of the interations of the 'For each' loop is carried out sequentially so none of these would interupt each other anyway even if they used common objects shared across the individual instances.

Comment: Thank you Ian. Your reply reinforces my actions. I was afraid I am misinterpreting the use of property classes and methods. I am trying to leave a [vb6].Net mentality, if you catch the humor in that.